# Version Number Of The Last Published Component

Tags: tridion

In the CM, we have created components and published them. There have been edits done to the components after publishing. We wanted to find out the version number of the component that was published.  I could not find to get this information from the GUI. When I looked at the DB I could see the version information in the items table while item_states table has the publishing info but it does not contain the version reference. Now, with this information I will have to write a complex query comparing the publish dates in the item_states and item table.

Is there an alternate (easier) way to find this information?

Comment: The best solution depends on how you want to use this information. Could you clarify this?

Answer (score 2):

SDL Tridion does not store version information on Published items, so that indeed isn't available through the GUI or the API.

There are basically two ways for you to "guess" this information:

1. Use the API to find the version of the item at the time it was Published
2. Query the database for this information

The second option might seem easier if you are into database queries, but let me remind you that it is an unsupported option. The data model of SDL Tridion is not public which means it does not have to stay the same in newer releases. So if you query the database, your solution will not necessarily be future proof.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the other options mentioned, you could:

1. Implement some events system code that responds to the events that are triggered when a component is saved, and when it is successfully published
2. In your templates, dynamically add metadata to the component presentation as it is published, making the version (and maybe other things) available as metadata in the broker database.

As Arjen has commented, given more information about your problem, we could help you more.